# Azure Join AD Failed in Windows 10

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-10

I wanted to Join my Windows 10 device to Azure AD, but unfortunately I'm getting this below error, i tried to solve this issue by Disable/Enable Auto enrollment, Microsoft intune Settings etc. but still this issue is not solved. I'm using AD P1 Premium currently, Even i registered my device using P1 license 6 months ago, but now i can't able to register new devices.

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

Kindly disable the MDM settings in the Azure portal. After Turning off MDM and MAM check whether you were able to join the device to Azure AD.

Kindly let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

1. Login to https://portal.azure.com with your administrator
   credentials.
2. Select Azure Active Directory on the left.
3. Go to Devices and then select Device Settings.
4. Set Users may join devices to Azure AD to All or Selected.